# Como chamar o valor de uma variável?

Tags: java, jtextarea

Como poderei chamar o valor de uma variável de uma função, para dentro de outra função?

Estou a usar o `jPanel`, em que vou adicionar um texto com:

```
 jTextArea.append("AREA = " + /*AQUI*/);
```

Onde diz AQUI eu queria meter o valor de uma variável que tenho noutra class:

```
 public int setCoordenadasB(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    p.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
    p.y = Math.min(y1, y2);
    largura = Math.abs(x1-x2);
    altura = Math.abs(y1-y2);
    area = largura * altura;
    return area;
}
```

Era essa "area" que eu gostava de meter no AQUI lá em cima.

O método `setCoordenadasB` está numa `class` chamada rectângulo e `jTextArea` está na função `main`, e o objecto rectângulo foi iniciado como:

```
r = new Retangulo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria uma simples chamada de método, presumindo que você já tenha as 2 coordenadas em 4 variáveis coincidentemente de mesmo nome dentro do método `main()`:

```
jTextArea.append("AREA = " + r.setCoordenadasB(x1, y1, x2, y2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/PassArguments.java).

Comment: [função main](http://prntscr.com/9j578y)
[class rectangulo](http://prntscr.com/9j57us)
[iniciar r](http://prntscr.com/9j58lv)

Como estas imagens espero que me possa explicar melhor, o que queria saber era como poderei fazer com que o jTextArea.append funcione.

Comment: Aí você está mudando completamente a pergunta, eu respondi o que foi perguntado. Se quer saber outra coisa, precisa fazer outra pergunta. Este novo código não tem nenhuma relação com o que foi perguntado. Eu só posso responder o que foi perguntado, não tem como eu adivinhar o que você realmente queria.

Comment: Peço desculpa então, irei fazer outra pergunta, posso ter me explciado mal. 
Caso possa responder ao meu novo topico, agradecia.

Comment: Já coloquei uma nova questão, desta vez com prints do meu codigo para facilitar a compreensão de quem me possa ajudar, obrigado pelo conselho.
Novo Topico: [Topico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105690/duvida-sobre-o-jtextarea-append-adicionar-o-valor-da-variavel-area-ao-borderl)