# Duvida sobre o jTextArea.append (adicionar o valor da variavel 'area' ao BorderLayout) - Java

Tags: java, coordenadas, textarea, jtextarea

Estou com um problema numa linha de código, nesta linha que está sublinhada na imagem, dá-me um erro que diz que as coordenadas x1, y1, x2, y2 tem de ser estáticas, acontece que esta aplicação consiste em desenhar um rectângulo com o rato, logo o seu tamanho é indefinido, e preciso de calcular a sua área e meter na parte **debaixo** da BorderLayout, gostaria de saber como o posso fazer.

Linha de código que está a dar erro e que vos falo:
[image: Linha de código que me está a dar o erro:]

Aqui está a função que calcula a **Area**:

[image: Função que calcula a area:]

Aqui é onde está a inicialização do objecto em causa (RectanguloCheio):

[image: Inicialização do Objecto:]

Aqui está de onde vem as **coordenadas** x1,y1,x2,y2 (são todas do tipo inteiro):

[image: Coordenadas:]

**Para quem prefere o que esta em imagens em codigo:**

Linha de código que está a dar erro e que vos falo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Editor e = new Editor();
    JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
    PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point b = a.getLocation();
    int x = (int) b.getX();
    int y = (int) b.getY();

    e.add(jTextArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    e.setVisible(true);
    e.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //jTextArea.append("(x,y) = ("+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+", "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y+")");

    while (true) {
    jTextArea.append("(x,y) =("+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+", "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y+") ");
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(30);
            jTextArea.setText("");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e3)
        {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Aqui está a função que calcula a **Area**:

```
 @Override
public void setCoordenadas(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    p.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
    p.y = Math.min(y1, y2);
    largura = Math.abs(x1-x2);
    altura = Math.abs(y1-y2);
    area = largura * altura;
}

public int setCoordenadasB(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    p.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
    p.y = Math.min(y1, y2);
    largura = Math.abs(x1-x2);
    altura = Math.abs(y1-y2);
    area = largura * altura;
    return area;
}
```

Aqui é onde está a inicialização do objecto em causa (RectanguloCheio):

```
bRetanguloCheio = new JButton ("RetânguloCheio");

    pBotoes.add(bRetanguloCheio);

    ActionListener acRetanguloCheio = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            r = new RetanguloCheio();
            r.setColor(cor);
        }
    };
    bRetanguloCheio.addActionListener(acRetanguloCheio);
```

Aqui está de onde vem as **coordenadas** x1,y1,x2,y2 (são todas do tipo inteiro):

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    x1 = e.getX();
    y1 = e.getY();
    mousePressionado = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    x2 = e.getX();
    y2 = e.getY();
    r.setCoordenadas(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    r.setCoordenadasB(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    pEdicao.repaint();
}
```

Se alguém me souber ajudar agradecia, **obrigado**.

Comment: Já editei a minha publicação, apenas estou a tentar fazer com que haja uma maior compreensão da minha duvida, visto que ja fim um tópico apenas com código e algumas pessoas não o entenderam.
Obrigado, caso me possa ajudar ou saiba alguém, agradeço.

Comment: De onde vem essas variaveis x1, x2, y1 e y2? O que á variavel r? Ela é iniciada dentro do main? Parece que o código postado não está completo.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, já adicionei as informações pedidas.

Comment: Pelo menos pra mim, ainda não está claro de onde vem as variaveis que falei, da linha do erro. Eu vi o que você salientou em negrito, mas o código em volta da linha do erro não está claro de onde vem as variaveis que citei. Sugiro que dê uma lida em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve)

Comment: o x1, y1, x2, y2 são coordenadas que vem do getx() e do gety(), que sao valores obtidos pelo rato, ao selecionar um ponto e arrastar o rato, ele vai fazer um rectangulo, a única coisa que quero é calcular a area desse rectângulo a medida que o rectângulo está a ser criado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este é o código utilizado na função **main**, em que faz a chamada a função **mostrarInfo()** de cada class, o meu projecto tinha varias figuras, mas em questão na minha pergunta estava a figura **rectângulo**, o código colocado na função main é:

```
public void textoSul () {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    info.setText("(x,y) =("+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+", "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y+")");
                    if(r != null && r.p.x != 0) {
                        info.append (r.mostrarInfo());
                    }
                    else if (lista.size()>0) {
                        info.append(lista.get(lista.size()-1).mostrarInfo());
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        info.setText("");
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e3)
                    {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }   
            }

        });
        t.start();
    }
```

> **NOTA:** Este código, mostra as coordenadas do rato da tela toda e mostra as informações das figuras apenas no momento em que começarem a ser desenhadas.

O código colocado dentro da class **Rectângulo** é:

```
@Override
    public String mostrarInfo() {
        return (" Area = " +Area() +" Perimetro = " +Perimetro()+
                " Ponto Inicial = " +p.x + "," +p.y +" largura = " + largura +" altura = "+altura);
    }
```

> **NOTA:** Com este código são mostradas as informações como a **Area** o **Perímetro**, o **Ponto Inicial** a **Largura** e a **Altura** do Rectângulo.
>   Para que isto aconteça é necessário ter pré-definido as funções correspondestes à Área e restantes informações.

Caso alguem tenha duvidas de como fazer essas funções ou duvidas em como mostrar estas informações em outras figuras pode consultar o seguinte **link**: [soeiromass GitHub](https://github.com/soeiromass/Editor-GeometricalFigures/), os ficheiros java estão localizados na directoria: "Editor-GeometricalFigures/src/editor/".